# latex being stuck and not displaying page 2

Tags: warnings

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Amanuel Negash.
Introduction to modern physics\\
1.question number 1\\
$\frac{c-w}{c+w}=\frac{((c-u)(c-v))}{((c+u)(c+v))}
(c-w)((c+u)(c+v)=(c+w)((c-u)(c-v))\\
c(c+u)(c+v)-w(c+u)(c+v)=c(c-u)(c-v)+w(c-u)(c-v)\\
c(c+u)(c+v)-c(c-u)(c-v)=w(c+u)(c+v)+w(c-u)(c-v)\\
c[(c+u)(c+v)-(c-u)(c-v)]=w[(c+u)(c+v)+(c-u)(c-v)]\\
w=\frac{c[(c+u)(c+v)-(c-u)(c-v)]}{(c+u)(c+v)+(c-u)(c-v)}$\\
$w=\frac{c[c^2+(cu)+(cv)+uv-[c^2-(cu)-(cv)+uv]}{c^2+(cu)+(cv)+uv-[c^2-(cu)-(cv)+uv}$\\
\newpage
$w=\frac{2c[cv+cu]}{2[c^2+uv]}$$\\
$$w=\frac{c^2(v+u)*1/c^2}{[c^2+uv]*1/c^2}$\\
$w=\frac{v+u}{1+\frac{u*v}{C*C}}$\\

2. question number 2\\
first I want to proof $cosh(a+b)$ and $sinh(a+b)$ to their respective identities that will help me solve the problem. 


\end{document}
```

what is the wrong with the document that makes it display this error. I want to add pages but it seems latexmaker does not let me do it. any suggestions please.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--14
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is not an error but a warning. Your code *does* compile. At the same time, there is considerable room for improvement. Starting with the statement that you should *never* use `\\ ` to enforce a line break (unless you are in a table).

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--14` is the warning you always get if you mis-use `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph. You also have _very_ weird use of  `$\\$`  with a math expression that just has a forced line break and no math???

Answer (score 1):

The warning you show is just a warning, not an error, however there are multiple places shown that `\\` and `$` are mis-used, also `cosh` should be `\cosh` otherwise it is set in math italic which has separated letters to look like a product of variables not a function name.

Perhaps something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\author{Amanuel Negash}
\title{Introduction to modern physics}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item question number 1
\begin{align*}
\frac{c-w}{c+w}&=\frac{((c-u)(c-v))}{((c+u)(c+v))}\\
(c-w)((c+u)(c+v)&=(c+w)((c-u)(c-v))\\
c(c+u)(c+v)-w(c+u)(c+v)&=c(c-u)(c-v)+w(c-u)(c-v)\\
c(c+u)(c+v)-c(c-u)(c-v)&=w(c+u)(c+v)+w(c-u)(c-v)\\
c[(c+u)(c+v)-(c-u)(c-v)]&=w[(c+u)(c+v)+(c-u)(c-v)]
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
w&=\frac{c[(c+u)(c+v)-(c-u)(c-v)]}{(c+u)(c+v)+(c-u)(c-v)}\\
w&=\frac{c[c^2+(cu)+(cv)+uv-[c^2-(cu)-(cv)+uv]}{c^2+(cu)+(cv)+uv-[c^2-(cu)-(cv)+uv}\\
w&=\frac{2c[cv+cu]}{2[c^2+uv]}\\
w&=\frac{c^2(v+u)*1/c^2}{[c^2+uv]*1/c^2}\\
w&=\frac{v+u}{1+\frac{u*v}{C*C}}\\
\end{align*}

\item question number 2

first I want to prove $\cosh(a+b)$ and $\sinh(a+b)$ to their respective identities that will help me solve the problem. 

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```